# C#/WPF Ink Stroke with IsManipulationEnabled?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multi-touch, inkcanvas

I'm creating a simple multitouch WPF application with inkcanvas. Right now it is possible to use gestures (**zooming, moving, rotating**) with images in the inkcanvas, but ink strokes do not have the **IsManipulationEnabled** property, so the code I made for **UIElements** is not valid for ink strokes.

Any idea about hwo to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to get the points from a stroke and redraw them in another drawable class that inherits from `UIElement` like `System.Windows.Shapes.Path`. Not the most elegant solution but workable.